# insert data into mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

$cxn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("failed to connect to mysql:" . mysql_error());

$barcode = $_POST['barcode'];
$manufacturer = $_POST['manufacturer'];
$product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$model_no = $_POST['model_no'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$color = $_POST['color'];
$image_path = $_POST['image_path'];
$others = $_POST['others'];


mysql_select_db("estinno",$cxn);
$sql="INSERT INTO details (barcode, manufacturer, product_name, category, model_no, price, color, image_path, others) VALUES ('$barcode', '$manufacturer', '$product_name', '$category', '$model_no', '$price', '$color', '$image_path', '$others')";

echo "Barcode details Successfully Added";

?>
```

I have seen all such related question, but none of them working here.

Comment: You forget to execute the query I think. `mysql_query()`

Comment: It looks like you're using the old mysql interface, which is deprecated. You should switch to mysqli or pdo if possible. Also please try to use prepared statements or make sure that you escape your query parameters correctly.

Comment: Did you get any errors

Comment: no errors, but it is not getting inserted into database

Comment: I think it may be helpful for you to read up on [SQL-Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/448591), if you haven't heard of it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotton to run your SQL.  Add:

```
$insert = mysql_query($sql);

if($insert){
    echo "Barcode details Successfully Added";
} else {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

..and please update your code to use mysqli_* or PDO.  mysql_* functions are being deprecated.

Comment: will do what you said. will update to mysqli soon.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that your query parameters are escaped correctly, you can use prepared statements. Together with mysqli a solution can look like this:

```
<?php

$cxn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","estinno") or die("failed to connect to mysql:" . mysqli_error($con));

$barcode = $_POST['barcode'];
$manufacturer = $_POST['manufacturer'];
$product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$model_no = $_POST['model_no'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$color = $_POST['color'];
$image_path = $_POST['image_path'];
$others = $_POST['others'];

$stmt = $cxn->prepare('INSERT INTO details (barcode, manufacturer, product_name, category, model_no, price, color, image_path, others) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->bind_param('sssssssss', $barcode, $manufacturer, $product_name, $category, $model_no, $price, $color, $image_path, $others);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

echo "Barcode details Successfully Added";
```

Comment: thanks, will update to mysqli soon.